# Bash: For loop single line

Tags: bash, android

```
for i in {1..4}; do echo "Welcome $i";done
```

I want

```
Welcome 1
Welcome 2
.
.
```

Instead I get

```
welcome {1..4}
```

Android terminal emulator

Comment: Are you sure you are on `bash`? Whats the output of `echo $0`?

Comment: The vast majority of Android machines use some variation of `busybox`, not `bash`.  Use [termux](https://termux.com/) if you want `bash` or `zsh`.

Comment: Similar (duplicate?): [Why is brace expansion not supported?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/92819)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not running `bash`, or you're running an older version of `bash`, or a shell that doesn't understands brace expansions.

The most probable explanation is that your terminal emulator is running `/bin/sh` or some smaller shell (which is hopefully still mostly POSIX compliant).

In `bash` (and any other shell that supports brace expansions), your explicit for-loop may be changed into an implicit loop:

```
printf 'Welcome %d\n' {1..4}
```

or

```
printf 'Welcome %d\n' $(seq 4)
```

if you don't have brace expansion but do have `seq`.

Comment: brace expansion usually refers to the `{x,y}` csh feature from the late 70s (and added to ksh and many other Korn-like shells in the 80s). `{1..4}` is a zsh extension (from 1995) added to some other shells much later (in the 2000s, 2010s).

Comment: Sorry, while brace expansion was added to bash and zsh from the start (1989, 1990) to pdksh in 1992, it was never added to ksh88.  I don't know when it was added to ksh93, possibly from the start as ksh93d (1995) had it already.

Answer (score 4):

You are running in /bin/sh (shell), not /bin/bash.

```
$ /bin/sh -c 'for i in {1..4}; do echo "Welcome $i";done'
Welcome {1..4}
```

Now try with bash:

```
$ /bin/bash -c 'for i in {1..4}; do echo "Welcome $i";done'
Welcome 1
Welcome 2
Welcome 3
Welcome 4
```

If you prefer shell then do as Nikolas write:

```
for i in $(seq 4); do echo "Welcome $i" ; done
```

but I would suggest to use Bash.

Comment: The path doesn't matter. When running as `/bin/sh`, `bash` or `ksh` or `zsh` still expand `{1..4}`. The point would be that `/bin/sh` on that system is probably not based on `zsh`, `ksh` or `bash` but maybe on the Almquist shell (which doesn't have the feature) or `yash` where the feature is not  enabled by default. In any case, that feature should not be used in `sh` scripts as that's not a standard `sh` feature, so the recommendation to use `bash` explicitly is certainly a good one.

Answer (score 2):

As [Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/369914/208450) said, either you're not running bash or the version is not very *recent*. I've tested the following in older versions of bash (maybe before it formed its idiom?) and it works with `sh` too:

```
for i in `seq 1 4`;do echo "Welcome $i";done
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: That `{1..4}` zsh feature was added to `bash` in 3.0. It's possible the OP uses a Solaris 8 or 9 system for instance that would come with an older version (IIRC; in an optional package).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas OP uses Android terminal emulator, therefore he uses Android. Link to this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

If you use this app: [Android terminal emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en), "then it is a terminal emulator for communicating with the built-in Android shell". That is, if you didn't install your own version of bash manually (your device should be rooted for this. Were you rooting your device?), then you have default Android shell, not bash. Therefore, you can use only Android's shell feature set, and can't use advanced bash syntax and features, for example: `{1..4}`.

**Some information, which I found.**

- [Android terminal emulator FAQ](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions)
- [Android Shell Command Reference](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/wiki/Android-Shell-Command-Reference) - how states in FAQ "a brief, incomplete, guide to using the built-in Android shell"